# Pivot table which filters taking the current week and past 5 weeks

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which takes data and sorts by week. After refreshing the data, every week I need to open the filters of the week and select the new week in order to show the data. Is there a macro or process to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do could be basic enough for the Record Macro feature to help you out. If you haven't used the Record Macro feature before, all you need to do is start recording a macro and change the filtered date in your pivot table; once you've done that at least once, stop recording the macro and take a look at the macro's code. Assuming you manually did what you want the macro to automate for you, a large majority of your code should be usable for creating a macro that's more along the lines of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to your base data called 'Last five weeks' or something similar. Now, assuming your date field is called 'Date', fill this column with the formula:

```
=[@[Date]]>=(TODAY()-35)
```

This formula returns TRUE if the date is within 35 days of today and FALSE if it is older than this. (Magic number 35 is 5 weeks of 7 days.)

Go to your pivot table and filter the whole table on TRUE. Every time you update your pivot table you will only get the last five weeks of data - you could update your table automatically using the advice from MattCoats.